# Probability of suspects guilty or not guilty

Tags: probability

After a crime, the police arrest 10 suspects. Of the 10, 4 actually committed the crime. 3 random suspects are chosen for interrogation. What is the probability that all 3 suspects are guilty or all 3 suspects are innocent?

We can see that $P(guilty)=\frac{4}{10}$ and $P(not\ guilty)=\frac{6}{10}$.

After this, I am somewhat confused about how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 5):

We try to pick three guilty criminals in a row.

Pick a criminal. What's the chance they are guilty? (It's $\frac{4}{10}$, you have already mentioned this yourself).

So *after* you have taken this criminal out of the queue, select a second criminal. What is the chance that this second criminal is also guilty? (Hint: it's not $\frac{4}{10}$.)

Multiply those two chances and repeat for the third criminal.

The approach for the innocent suspects is very similar.

Answer (score 1):

The probability is $(\frac{4}{10}\times \frac{3}{9}\times\frac{2}{8})+(\frac{6}{10}\times \frac{5}{9}\times \frac{4}{8})$, which simplifies to $\frac{1}{30}+\frac{5}{30}=\frac{6}{30}=\frac{1}{5}$, demonstrating the actualization of the logic Alexander Geldhof presented in his response.